# TFS Build: How to execute post-build event

Tags: tfsbuild, post-build-event

I have asp.net mvc project. I am updating some JavaScript files in the post-build event. It has the next format - `"helperApp /sourceFolder /destinationFolder"`. It works great. But when I try to build it on TFS build server I have received the error (255 cant open file). It was happened because `"C:\Build\.."` folder and files inside are read only. So I can't update my JavaScript files.

I had similar issue when used WebDeploy from developer machine (files in `destinationFolder` were locked) but I fix this by using command "Check out for edit" from VS (It makes them writable).

My question: How is it possible to get access `helperApp` to project's files in post-build event during TFC build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is why are you editing source-controlled files as part of the build?  Do you intend to check-in the changes as part of the build also?

You will need to update the build (either the TFS Workflow, or your MSBuild Targets) to Check-Out the files from TFS before attempting to modify them (or simply turn-off the Read-Only flag), then either Check-In when done modifying them or Undo Checkout on them.

Comment: Related to first question. I implemented multilingual support. I have added resource's files (i.e.: *.en.resx, *.fr.resx) in asp.net mvc project. I wanted to use the values from these resources in JavaScript files. So I created js resources (i.e.: Resources.en.js, Resources.fr.js) add some C# code that manages which one Resource.*.js file was needed to use. Next my issue that I have to update Resource.*.js files each time when I change my *.resx files.

Comment: This was implemented in post-build event. I call my helper app that from directory `sourceFolder`takes .resx files and creates Resource.*.js files in `destinationFolder`. My app takes resource`s values from `destinationFolder`. So I need to have possibility to edit Resource.*.js after build.

Comment: I have added check of read only attribute and just remove it if file has it.